# MS Teams: Created team with PS is not visible in admin.teams portal but is in teams app

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-online

I create all our teams in powershell. From the 900 there is 1 with problems.

It is visible in:

- teams app
- endpoint
- in powershell with get-team -groupid "   "

not visible in:

- admin.teams portal
- admin.sharepoint portal
- admin.microsoft portal
- PS Get-Team -DisplayName "2BB - Maatschappelijke vorming - (22)test" -> no result
- PS Get-Team -> is not in the list of all teams

In Sharepoint en microsoft.admin I get the option to create a team for the site/group but that doesn't work (because it already exist).

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the "900" ? What is your PowerShell command to create the team ?

Comment: Give it some time and then refresh the admin portals and check again